# Left outer join linq query object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have three table to which i performed inner join on two table and than the left outer join
Why the below query is returning me this error
  "linq query object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
  var model = from p in Uow.Instance.RepoOf<RoleMenuMetrix>().GetAll()
            from n in Uow.Instance.RepoOf<NavigationMenu>().GetAll().Where(q => q.Id == p.MenuId)
            from m in
                Uow.Instance.RepoOf<NavigationButton>()
                    .GetAll()
                    .Where(q => q.NavigationMenuId == n.Id)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
            where p.RoleId == Guid.Parse("96246E99-6BF2-4A3D-8D2C-263DDEF2F97B")
                  && n.IsActive && n.ApplicationName == "MEM"
            select new
            {
                p.MenuId,
                p.RoleId,
                n.Name,
                n.ParentId,
                ButtonName = m.ButtonName == null ? "" : m.ButtonName // when i comment this it works fine
            };
```

The below query in linqPad works fine

```
from p in P_RoleMenuMetrixes
from n in NavigationMenus.Where(q => q.Id == p.MenuId)
from m in NavigationButtons.Where(q => q.NavigationMenuId == n.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
where p.RoleId == Guid.Parse("96246E99-6BF2-4A3D-8D2C-263DDEF2F97B")
&& n.IsActive && n.ApplicationName == "MEM"
select new
{
    p.MenuId,
    p.RoleId,
    n.Name,
    n.ParentId,
    m.ButtonName
}
```

Error Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I think it is because there is no relevant `NavigationButton`.

Comment: what is  current error?

Comment: Same error as defined "linq query object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: What does `GetAll()` return? Just the `DbSet`?

Comment: GetAll() returns IQuerable<T>

Comment: The screen shot tells something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx), default value is assigned when no matches are found, so you need to check for `null` and assign proper value, something like this:-

```
ButtonName = m!= null ? m.ButtonName  : String.Empty
```

Here I am considering `ButtonName` is `string` if it's not you can change the query accordingly.

Comment: @KinnanNawaz - Oops my bad! You should be checking `m` for null and not `m.ButtonName` as that is the source of error. Please test my update it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check null value , use following code

```
   ButtonName = m== null ?   "": m.ButtonName
```

Answer (score 0):

The error reveals a much more serious flaw in your code. The LINQ statement does not translate into one SQL statement (as the LINQ you execute in Linqpad), but three separate statements of which the results are connected in memory. So it's just LINQ to objects. Hence the null reference.

Your UoW/Repo architecture requires major revision! You've disabled composability of LINQ statements. `GetAll()` should not return a `List<T>` (as the screenshot shows) but `IQueryable<T>`, i.e. the `DbSet`.

Currently, `GetAll()` will always fetch the whole table into memory. Any filtering you do afterwards does not affect the SQL statement.